# How to keep values after submiting/ closing dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to, when I double click the card and pick out a date from the calender, put a string value to input field and create a dynamic checkbox. Then, after closing the dialog, and double clicking again on the same card, I want the same values to be shown in this dialog. Later, when I add a new card, I want the dialog to be empty.

I have tried fix it by my self, but couldn't.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/62QY8/19/)

Html:

```
<!--Wrapper div-->
    <div id="wrapper">

        <!--Inbox list and button to add a card-->
        <div id="inboxList" class="cellContainer">
            <p style="display: inline">Inbox</p> 
            <!--Button to add a Card-->
            <input type="button" id="AddCardBtn" value="+ Add a Card..."/> <hr class="fancy-line"/> <br/>

            <!--Card div-->
            <div id="userAddedCard"> <br/>
                <div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
    <!--Modal Dialog-->
    <div id="modalDialog">

        <form>
            <label>Title</label>
            <input type="text" id="customTextBox" value="some value"/>
            <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" value="some date"/></p> 
            <input type="button" id="Getbtn" value="Get value"/> <hr/><br/>

            <label>Add checkBox</label>
            <br />
            <div id="progressbar"></div>
            <br />
            <input type="text" id="checkBoxName" />
            <input type="button" id="btnSaveCheckBox" value="_Ok" />
            <br />

        </form>

    </div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(function () {
    // Click function to add a card
    var $div = $('<div />').addClass('sortable-div'); 
    $('<label>Title</label><br/>').appendTo($div);              
    $('<input/>', { "type": "text","class":"ctb"}).appendTo($div);
    $('<input/>', { "type": "text","class":"date"}).appendTo($div);
    var cnt =0,$currentTarget;
    $('#AddCardBtn').click(function () {
      var $newDiv = $div.clone(true);
      cnt++;  
      $newDiv.prop("id","div"+cnt);  
      $('#userAddedCard').append($newDiv);
//      alert($('#userAddedCard').find("div.sortable-div").length);        
    });

    // Double click to open Modal Dialog Window
    $('#userAddedCard').dblclick(function (e) {
        $currentTarget = $(e.target);

        $('#modalDialog').dialog({
            modal: true,
            height: 600,
            width: 500,
            position: 'center'
        });
        return false;

    });
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({showWeek:true, firstDay:1});

    $("#Getbtn").on("click",function() {
      var val = $("#customTextBox").val();
      $currentTarget.find(".ctb").val(val);
      $currentTarget.find(".date").val($("#datepicker").val() );

        document.getElementById('customTextBox').value="";
        document.getElementById('datepicker').value="";
        $('.allcheckbox').remove();

      $('#modalDialog').dialog("close");
    });

    // Add a new checkBox
    $('#btnSaveCheckBox').click(function () {
        addCheckbox($('#checkBoxName').val());
        $('#checkBoxName').val("");
    });

    function addCheckbox(name) {
        var container = $('#modalDialog');
        var inputs = container.find('input');
        var id = inputs.length + 1;

        $('<input />', { type: 'checkbox', class: 'allcheckbox', id: 'cb' + id, value: name }).appendTo(container);
        $('<label />', { 'for': 'cb' + id, class: 'allcheckbox',  text: name }).appendTo(container);
        $('<br/>').appendTo(container);


    }    

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in the `dblclick` callback, before showing the dialog:

```
$('#modalDialog #customTextBox').val($currentTarget.children('.ctb').val());
$('#modalDialog #datepicker').val($currentTarget.children('.date').val());
```

This code takes input field values from the selected card and puts them into dialog input fields.

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/62QY8/24/)

As regards checkboxes, you have to save them as javascript values and attach them to the card element, but I think it's too difficult to change your code (which is a bit messy, to be honest) and get it to work. You should implement the [model/view pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) to decouple view (card html elements) from data (input values and checkbox labels). May I suggest you use [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org) to achieve this?

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I add this code $('#modalDialog #checkboxes').val($currentTarget.children('.allcheckbox').val());     and removed this $('.allcheckbox').remove(); The problem now is, when I add new card and double click on it still the same values for the checkboxs are shown. Could it be possible to make if/else ??

Comment: I tried something like that but it doesn't work:(                     if ($currentTarget == $cnt) {
            $('#modalDialog #checkboxes').val($currentTarget.children('.allcheckbox').val());
        }
        else {
            $('.allcheckbox').remove();
        }

Comment: If I understood what you're trying to do, you want different checkboxes for each card, and they should not appear on the card but in the dialog, right? In this case you can't use `$('#modalDialog #checkboxes').val($currentTarget.children('.allcheckbox').val());`. You must store and retrieve checkbox data with jquery `.data()` function. Please give me some time and I'll post a working example.

Comment: This is your code changed to store checkbox data. http://jsfiddle.net/62QY8/32/
Watch for changes on lines 20, 33-39, 60, 71, 77-80, 82, 87-89, 98.
Anyway, I insist: that's not the right way to do this thing.

Comment: Thank you very very much. It was exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you :) . I have big troubles implementing this by my self, now it works.

Comment: Just for asking: Are you creating an array for checkboxs ? $newDiv.data('checkboxes', []);

Comment: Yes, I create one array for each card and one for the dialog.

Comment: I Implement a progressbar. I want also reset the progressbar, when I add new card. Do you have any idea to fix it? Here is the link, what I implement: http://jsfiddle.net/62QY8/34/